# In Robo Rally, can any number of robots be pushed?

Tags: robo-rally

The rules imply to me that one robot can push a line of robots away. Does anyone know of clarifications or have another reading of it? What I mean is the situation where A robot on cell 1A pushes toward a robot on cell 1B and there are more robots occupying 1C, 1D, etc.

> **Pushing Other Robots:**
>   When robots collide, one will push the other. Robots can be pushed anywhere on the board (or off the side!), even into a pit or onto a conveyor belt. A robot can’t be pushed through a wall, though, so the movement of a pushing robot will simply stop if the pushed robot runs into a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They had the same discussion on [bgg](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/72097/pushing-question). Yes you can push multiple robots.

Comment: Were any of the posters on Board Game Geek affiliated with the game? I don't think that the collective opinion of several forum posters is a definitive answer.

Comment: IIRC the rules are rather clear that, yes, multiple robots can be pushed.